# Is "as fast" a kind of abbreviation?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrases

From *Friends*(Season 02, Episode 04): [Transcript](http://www.friendstranscripts.tk)

> the turns aren't as fast but when Snoopy falls. . . funny.

*The turn* is referring the movement when skating.

Is the phrase *as fast* is a kind of abbreviation of *as fast as he need to balance himself*? Or just the word has the meaning similar to *very*? Does this kind of usage of *as* very common?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look in the script; having more context is helpful. Here is the relevant part.

> JULIE: Where you goin'?
>   PHOEBE: Um, I'm gonna go meet Duncan, he's skating tonight at the Garden, he's in the Capades.
>   JOEY: The Ice Capades?
>   CHANDLER: No, no, the gravel capades. Yeah, the turns aren't **as fast** but when Snoopy falls... funny.

I think this Capades should refer to the **[Ice Capades](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_Capades)**, and it seems like Duncan was in the Ice Capades. However, Chandler made fun of him (Duncan––or Joey himself, as hunter suggested in the comments below) when Joey asked about which Capades. Chandler said it's not the Ice Capades but the gravel capades. (Note the capitalization. Ice Capades is a proper noun, but "gravel capades" is not.)

And this phrase ***"as fast"*** would refer to the fact that the turns in the gravel capades wouldn't be as fast as the turns in the Ice Capades. (I laughed while reading the script. *Friends* always makes me laugh. :-)

Comment: +1 I think though that Duncan is actually in the Ice Capades and Chandler is making fun of JOEY for being dumb.

Comment: @hunter Thank you. I think you're absolutely right!

Comment: (I gotta defend Joey on this one though... I'm not from New York City and have never heard of the Ice Capades.)